# How to change the browser URL without reload the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react routers and to change the URL I'm doing history.push(pathname), But it is reloading
entire page. I don't want to refresh or reload the page, I tried with replace and replacestate still page is reloading could anyone suggest me the solution?

```
 history.push(
        `/dashboard/filter?studyName=${JSON.stringify(study_dashboard_new)?JSON.stringify(study_dashboard_new):JSON.stringify([])}&compoundName=${JSON.stringify(compound_dashboard_new)?JSON.stringify(compound_dashboard_new):JSON.stringify([])}`
    );
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you are seeing, or calling, "reloading entire page"? `history.push` doesn't reload the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `history` from the `react-router-dom`'s `useHistory` hook.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom only but some how page is reloading.How to avoid that?

Comment: Can you update the question with more code? From where exactly you are getting the `history` object? Also, have you wrapped your main app in `<BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter>`?